# Setting up redis cache for remote connections

Tags: redis

I have just installed a Redis Cache on a windows server using the rdis package (https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis).

It runs under localhost fine.

My problem is what do I need to do to connect to this cache instance from a remote connection?

I am trying to connect to the ip address of the server I get the below error. I get the same error using the server name.

What needs to be done to expose the cache?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify the redis conf, set the protected mode to no and bind the public ip of your machine.

Comment: Would that be in the redis.windows.conf on a windows machine?